# How do I compare 2 eloquent collections and remove whats in one from the other?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a collection of all doors, and a collection of doors that the current user has access to.  How can I compare the two and remove from the all doors collection the doors the user already has access to?

```
$doors = Door::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
$users_doors = $user->doors;
```

Here are the two collections.

Comment: This you can achieve this using relationship with where clause

Comment: Can you please update your question with table structure and Model classes

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Collection::diff()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-diff):

```php
$doorsWithAccess = $doors->diff($users_doors);
```