# Laravel Remove Model entries from Collection

Tags: php, laravel

Given this Laravel collection:

```
$a = collection([
  Model User #1,
  Model User #2,
  Model User #3
  ...
]);

$b = collection([
  Model User #1,
  Model User #3
]);
```

How can I remove entries from `$a` that are listed on `$b` resulting in a collection with only `Model User #2`?

Comment: How are you generating these `Collection`s? You should be able to simply omit specific models (based on ID) when querying, etc. Otherwise, check this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458183/how-do-i-compare-2-eloquent-collections-and-remove-whats-in-one-from-the-other

Comment: Thanks! `diff` was what I needed!